# Getting an specific item from List<>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem! I have found allots of people with the same problem but none of the answers helpt me.. Im trying to get an specific item from List<> but my result of "test" returns null, why?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var modelList = new Model2();
    modelList.MyPropertyList.Add(new Model1 { Name = "Hej1", MyProperty1 = true });

    modelList.MyPropertyList.Add(new Model1 { Name = "Hej2", MyProperty1 = false });

    var test = modelList.MyPropertyList.Find(x => x.Name == "Hej1").MyProperty1;
}
```

Comment: how do you know it is null?

Comment: When i debug the value is null..

Comment: Please post Model2 class code

Comment: are you sure you check the value after executing the line? try adding `MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());) and see what is the result

Comment: What is null, the object you're retrieving or the property?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without the code for `Model1` and `Model2` it isn't possible to say with any certainty what your issue might be.  As a guess, I'd suspect @dotctor is correct.

Comment: If the code is working, as you stated below, I recommend this question be closed.

Comment: @dotctor `test` is not defined before it gets invoked. How do you expect to do `MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());`. this is no JS.

Comment: Are you kidding me? you should put it after the line `var test = modelList.MyPropertyList.Find(x => x.Name == "Hej1").MyProperty1;`.

Comment: @dotctor Did you read what i've written ? it can only be tested after that line. yes. but your comment to him : "_are you sure you check the value after executing the line?_".....there is no other choice. otherwise it won't compile. `test` is only available after that line - so he MUST have run that line before .

Comment: @RoyiNamir well, there is.  You can stick a break point on that line and mouse over `test` and it will be `null`.  It seems likely that's what's happened.

Comment: VS shows the value is null before executing the command in autos windows. @RoyiNamir

Comment: @dotctor yes, if it's debug mode you're right. :-) anyway we both get the idea. my comment was referencing when running.(after that line)

Answer (score 3):

According to the OP Comments

> how do you know it is null? –  dotctor 1 hour ago
>   When i debug the value is null.. –  Dennis Eriksson 1 hour ago

---

> are you sure you check the value after executing the line? try adding
>   `MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());) and see what is the result – 
>   dotctor 1 hour ago

---

> I feel a shame of my question.. It was working the whole time! It was
>   my fault that i read the value before it was declared to "test"! But
>   thanks!! –  Dennis Eriksson 1 hour ago

---

I think the problem is **in the way you debugged** your program. You have put a breakpoint on line `var test = modelList.MyPropertyList.Find(x => x.Name == "Hej1").MyProperty1;` and the execution stops right before this line **but you think that this line is already executed** and **Visual Studio shows the value of `test` as `null` in Autos window** and this makes you think that the `test` is really null. If you **continue execution** by pressing `F10` or add a line like  `MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());` just to make the previous line executed or somehow show the value of `test` you will find that it is not `null`.

Comment: It's a shame to downvote an answer without comment it!. By the way, this is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Not much as an answer - but your code - should work fine.

```
void Main()
{
     var modelList = new Model2();
        modelList.MyPropertyList.Add(new Model1 { Name = "Hej1", MyProperty1 = true });
        modelList.MyPropertyList.Add(new Model1 { Name = "Hej2", MyProperty1 = false });
        var test = modelList.MyPropertyList.Find(x => x.Name == "Hej1").MyProperty1;
        Console.WriteLine (test);
}


public class Model1
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public bool? MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
 public List<Model1> MyPropertyList { get; set; }
 public Model2()
 {MyPropertyList = new List<Model1>();
 }
}
```

Result : `True`.

Comment: how this can be helpful as an answer?

Comment: @dotctor Do you expect me to put it as an comment ? it's just shows that the code  - as it simplicity - should work. Im not expecting it to be chosen as an answer.

Comment: If the OP's result is null, it would be safe to assume `MyProperty1` would be type `bool?`.

Comment: I do not except that from you. IMO If you think that the question is low quality you should vote for closing it.

Comment: @dotctor Why ? he did try to put an effort. I don't think the question is low quality

Comment: I feel a shame of my question.. It was working the whole time! It was my fault that i read the value before it was declared to "test"! But thanks!!

Comment: @DennisEriksson Happens to everyone :-)

Comment: I think the question has low quality because it contains a bug that we can not reproduce. The code is not complete, the method of checking the `test == null` is not mentioned.

Comment: @dotctor But in the end it was the answer.

Comment: the answer was what I said in the comments on OP, value is checked before executing the command. @Blam

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Find() try using the following:

```
var test = modelList.MyPropertyList.SingleOrDefault(model => model.Name == "Hej1");

if(test != null)
{
    //-- do something here
}
```

Comment: why should he use SingleOrDefault?